# When you change the fields in the models in django

Tags: django

After you initially create the model and you want to change the fields in the models. If you syncdb ,it replies no fixtures found, meaning to say the models has not recognised the change. One way to solve this is to delete the database and recreate the database but you lose all the data. Is there any other better solution? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) to help you for models changes. It will automatically detect any changes to models and generate appropriate script to update db schema.